# How can you send an NFT with Phantom Wallet in the web browser without React and using something like PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, C# server side?

Tags: spl-token, javascript, web3.js

How can you send an NFT with Solana API Client-Side in the web browser with Phantom Wallet without React, and with any Server-Side technology like PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, C#? Can anyone post a code sample of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is possible to generate the transaction object Client-Side but I later learned it isn't a secure way of doing it since all JavaScript Client-Side can be manipulated. The best way to do it is generate the transaction Server-Side and do the validation there, then Sign the transaction (once a transaction is signed there is protection so that then the fields cannot be edited without invalidating the transaction) then serialize the transaction and send it to the Client-Side to be created back into a Transaction object with Transaction.from() method, then you can use Phantom Wallet signAndSendTransaction there. Also in production it would probably be best to use a JavaScript obfuscator to scramble your Client-Side JavaScript as much as possible to add more protection that your Client-Side code will not be tampered with.

```
<h1>Testing</h1>

<div id="ttt">
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src="/solanaWeb3.browser.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/splToken.browser.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*
With this code, use Browserify to package @solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-token to use Client-Side in the browser with <script> tags
>> browserify -r @solana/web3.js -s solanaWeb3 -o solanaWeb3.browser.js
>> browserify -r @solana/spl-token -s splToken -o splToken.browser.js
Edit the rpc variable to your RPC. Edit the mint_public_key to the mint you want to transfer. Edit to_wallet_public_key to the wallet address you want to transfer to. Ensure the NFT you want to transfer is in the wallet you are currently signed into with Phantom Wallet and in Phantom Wallet Developer Settings set to either using Mainnet, Devnet, or which network you want it to use.
*/
// https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints
// It's better to use an RPC Endpoint from a provider like Quicknode or Alchemy which have higher API request limits.
let rpc = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
//let rpc = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
let mint_public_key = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("5NMaLhunZqqbx8S947rebHE9EBMk3ubjzZfGsUA5pVX9");
let to_wallet_public_key = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("67URVS4EEuznjqq6QBfYvrgKoZeGDXM2UfzbguhgiLBi");

let provider;
let publicKeyString;
let resp;
let wallet;

let getProvider = function () {
    if ('phantom' in window) {
        provider = window.phantom?.solana;

        if (provider?.isPhantom) {
            return provider;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = async function () {

    provider = getProvider();
    try {
        resp = await provider.connect();
        wallet = resp;
        publicKeyString = resp.publicKey.toString();
    } catch (err) {
        // { code: 4001, message: 'User rejected the request.' }
    }

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(splToken, null, 4));

    let eee = document.querySelector("#ttt");
    if (provider?.isPhantom) {
        eee.innerHTML = `Phantom Wallet Installed ` + publicKeyString;
    } else {
        eee.innerHTML = `Phantom Wallet Not Installed`;
    }

    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(rpc);

let transfer_amount = 1;
let transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();

/*
// Uncomment this to transfer Sol. 1,000,000,000 lamports is 1 Sol.
transaction.add(solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
toPubkey: to_wallet_public_key,
lamports: solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 2,
}));

Helpful links:
# https://spl.solana.com/token
# https://docs.phantom.app/
# https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/how-to-transfer-spl-tokens-on-solana
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560234/which-seeds-does-the-getassociatedtokenaddress-function-use-to-determine-the-a
*/

var source_public_key = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint_public_key, wallet.publicKey);

let zzz2 = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(to_wallet_public_key, { mint: mint_public_key });
//console.log(JSON.stringify(zzz2, null, 4));
//console.log(zzz2.value[0].pubkey);

if (zzz2?.value[0]?.pubkey) {
    var destination_public_key = zzz2?.value[0]?.pubkey;
    console.log("using pre-existing destination_public_key");
} else {
    var destination_public_key = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint_public_key, to_wallet_public_key);
    transaction.add(splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    wallet.publicKey,
    destination_public_key,
    to_wallet_public_key,
    mint_public_key,
    ));
}

transaction.add(splToken.createTransferInstruction(
source_public_key,
destination_public_key,
wallet.publicKey,
1,
));

    let blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    blockhash = blockhash.blockhash;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
    let signature = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
    signature = signature.signature;
    let jjj = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
}
</script>
```